# Bootstrap modal / optional new window

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to get Bootstrap modal windows working along with an href.  I want to allow the href to be right clickable so that you can use the browser to open the link in a new tab, however, if the link is just clicked then I want the modal window to operate as normal

http://www.bootply.com/VkbgGZjcWf

In the example bootply the bottom link (“This click loads the modal”) will load the modal window laid out on the page and you can still right click the link to go to the bbc home page

The top link is the one I am struggling with.  Bootstrap is trying to load the content of the href into the modal window, instead of showing the modal (as per the bottom link).

I suspect that it is something to do with the bottom link being an “http://...” External link whilst the top link is relative to the website itself… How do I get the top link work like the bottom one?

Comment: The issue is not that one modal uses an external URL. It's that Bootstrap (or the browser, or whatever) enforces a same-origin policy. No external link will be loaded. A fully-qualified internal URL will be, however.

Comment: Might it be a better user experience to provide a new window link in the modal?

Answer (score 0):

Apply `data-remote="false"` to your link.

**[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/KfFXsdz8NU)**

Bootstrap says...

> **This option is deprecated since v3.3.0 and will be removed in v4. We recommend instead using client-side templating or a data binding framework, or calling jQuery.load yourself.**
>
> If a remote URL is provided, content will be loaded one time via
>   jQuery's load method and injected into the .modal-content div. If
>   you're using the data-api, you may alternatively use the href
>   attribute to specify the remote source.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options

[A similar SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718628/twitter-bootstrap-modal-window-fallback-link)